# Finding Duplicate URLs

Tags: mysql, duplication

The following `URL` `varchar(2000)` row holds URL values in a 3rd party database that I'm accessing directly, i.e. going around the HTTP API.

```
MySQL [database]> desc TABLE;
+--------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field              | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| URL                | varchar(2000) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
```

There can be a variable amount of slashes in the row's values.

Example:

`MySQL [database]> select URL from TABLE where URL LIKE 'https://%//%';`

returns a single row:

`https://foo.bar.com//...`

My server(API) issues a SQL query that plans to enforce the uniqueness of the URL's `$DOMAIN/$FIRST_PATH`.

To illustrate since my terms are not technical:

`SELECT URL FROM TABLE WHERE URL LIKE 'https://foo.bar.com/bippy/%'`

So, if this database had a single row:

`https://foo.bar.com/bippy/v1`

then the query should find a "duplicate" in:

`https://foo.bar.com/bippy/version1`

since `https://foo.bar.com/bippy/version1` starts with `https://foo.bar.com/bippy`, an already existing URL's prefix.

However, I'm concerned that this approach is fragile - especially if the input URL is https://foo.bar.com///bippy` - that wouldn't be caught by the query.

I'm considering calling `java.net.URI#normalize` to remove duplicate `/`'s in the URI from my API. However, I'm not sure that it's robust.

```
import java.net.URI
new URI("http://foo.bar.com//bippy///").normalize
```

> java.net.URI = http://foo.bar.com/bippy/

What's a sound way to find URL "duplicates", i.e. `$DOMAIN/$FIRST_PATH` approach in my database table?

Comment: Hi, First of all, welcome to the site. Around here we appreciate table definitions, sample data and expected output (or a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)). That helps us in creating the tables and testing our code before we post an answer.

Comment: `SELECT URL FROM T GROUP BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(URL,'/',4) HAVING COUNT(*)>1` This will try to group by all urls like `https://foo.bar.com/domain/` assuming you replaced the triple ///

Comment: We need a clearer definition of "duplicate".

Comment: Hi Rick - by duplicate, I mean that slashes should not result in inequality. Example: `http://a.b.c/d/e` should equal `http://a.b.c//d////e`

Comment: I ended up using a regular expression to compare URL's.